# How can I cache data returned from an ANgularJS $http call?

Tags: angularjs

I have some AngularJS Javascript code calls a web service
and gets a simple array of objects:

```
this.$http({url: '/api/Action/GetActions', method: "GET" })
    .success((data) => {
       self.Actions = data;
    })
```

Is there any way I can cache this so that I do not need to 
keep accessing the server? I'm not sure if this makes any 
difference but I use Protractor for my E2E tests. So I am 
looking for a solution that will work along with Protractor.
Ideally I would like to do this with only AngularJS code 
and not use an external library unless it's really needed.

Comment: Have you looked into web `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`?

Comment: Sorry I was not so clear. I would like to use local storage but I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/MClt4py2TmmNIQa7m1v6?p=preview) using `localStorage`.

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $http){

  $scope.getData = function(){
    if(!localStorage.getItem('ip')){
      $http.get('http://ip.jsontest.com/')
        .success(function(response){
          localStorage.setItem('ip', JSON.stringify(response));
          $scope.data = response 
          $scope.dataSource = 'Server';
        })
    }else{
      $scope.data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('ip'));
      $scope.dataSource = 'Cache';
    }
  };

});
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can make it only store the data in local storage for an hour or until the browser session closes?

Comment: SessionStorage will purge data after the session expires. As far as clearing after a certain amount of time I suppose you could set a timeout to clear it after an hour.